# How to get the current VM product_id to use in my query

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I need to display the product information from the `product` table. I also have another table, `manufacturer`.

I have a query to display the product manufacturer by joining the two tables.

How to get the current id of the product in the `WHERE` expression? Please see my query below

```
$query = "SELECT vmm.mf_name,vmm.mf_desc"
  . "FROM xxx_virtuemart_manufacturers_fr_fr AS vmm, 
          xxx_virtuemart_product_manufacturers as vmp"
. "WHERE vmm.virtuemart_manufacturer_id=vmp.virtuemart_manufacturer_id
      AND vmp.virtuemart_product_id=1 LIMIT 0, 30";
```

From the above query the `product_id` is 1. But I want a dynamic variable for the `virtuemart_product_id`.

Is there any solution? Please help me

Comment: vmp.virtuemart_product_id=$ID

Comment: That title doesn't go with the question.

Answer (score 1):

just bind it to a variable like

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$id = $result['id'];
```

Although you should be using mysqli or PDO, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a php array for that variable and loop the array running the query on each value. 
If you know the possible all values, you can use `vmp.virtuemart_product_id IN ('1', '2', '3', ...)`
You can also do a sub query such as `vmp.virtuemart_product_id = (SELECT value FROM ...)`

I am sorry. I answered as much as I can from what I understood from your question.